# Angular Httpclient post doesn't work, but i can't catch any exception

Tags: angular, typescript, http, post

So im trying to to make a POST with the http client to my rest api. I only have to send an ID, but it dosen't do anything at all, as if it wasn't there. No error messages etc.

**Tried it this way:**

```js
httpOptions = {

    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': localStorage.getItem("type")+" "+localStorage.getItem("token")})
  };

 public likePet(id : string){
    var url = environment.apiKey+"/match/cr";
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('id', id)

    console.log(url);
    try{
      console.log("t1");
      this.httpClient.post(url,{params: params},this.httpOptions);
    } catch (error){
      console.error(error);
    }
    console.log("t2");
 }
```

**and that way:**

```js
 httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': localStorage.getItem("type")+" "+localStorage.getItem("token")})
  };

public createMatch(matchid: number){
  console.log("////");
  return this.httpClient.post(environment.apiKey+"match/cr?id="+matchid,this.httpOptions).pipe(
    catchError((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      window.alert("Failed");
      throw err
    })
  )
}
```

**Tried it with a complete hardcoded url like: localhost:8080/api/match/cr?id=1**

And not even an error message. API working fine. My other http GET/POST methods working.
But this is my first POST without sending a JSON and im clueless.

Comment: You need to handle the response asynchronously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `post()` method returns an Observable. As far as I am concerned the call is sent as soon as you subscribe to that Observable. Wherever you call `createMatch()` try `createMatch(matchId).subscribe()` and see if something happens.

If you don't want to work with Observables but would rather like your response as a Promise you could write

```
 httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': localStorage.getItem("type")+" "+localStorage.getItem("token")})
  };

public createMatch(matchid: number){
  console.log("////");
  return this.httpClient.post(environment.apiKey+"match/cr?id="+matchid,this.httpOptions).pipe(
    catchError((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      window.alert("Failed");
      throw err
    })
  ).toPromise()
}
```

Comment: Thaaank you!! Oh god, i am stupid. I compleately forget the .subscribe()... Literally watching my other methods for an hour an i didn't noticed it how they differ from this...